# Is the color in seaborn heatmap based on z score?

Tags: python, graphics, seaborn

Is the color in seaborn heatmap based on z score?
Does anybody know the answer?

Answer (score 2):

The color in a seaborn heatmap is based on pure values, there is no normalization. It will only be based on Z-score if your values are already Z-score normalized.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to base your heatmap on Z scores without precomputing zscores you can use the `clustermap` of seaborn. `clustermap` accepts a z_score argument. Default is `None` but it can accept the value of `0` or `1`. `0` means z score is calculated on a row basis and `1` on column basis.

If you do not want to display the clustering in your final heatmap you also need to set `col_cluster` and `row_cluster` to `False`.

```
data_example = np.array([[100,50,-50,67],[0,1,-2,3],[4000,-4000,2000,-1000]]).T
sns.clustermap(data_example,z_score=1, col_cluster=False,row_cluster=False,cmap="RdBu_r")
```

Results in this heatmap that uses z score instead of the original values.

[image]

Comment: This is a fantastic resource. +1

Comment: Wonderful method!

Comment: Awesome method!